# Angular - use API with HTTP Digest Auth

Tags: angular, typescript, http, authentication

I want to create a web administration Panel. for this, I wrote a backend Controller that helps me deliver the required Data... However, there are some sensible Data and because of this reason, I implemented HTTP Digest auth. If you visit the site in Browser you can simply enter your Username and Password in the Browser generated login screen (standard Browser Auth Box) and if username/password is correct the Data are shown as JSON (or another specified format - It's a RESTful API).

I've tried for days to implement this in Angular but it doesn't work... - I've found some blog Posts with Instructions but there are only HTTP Basic authentication - and I don't want to use Basic auth.

I tried to send a Get request to the specified Url to get the realm/nonce and so on but this doesn't work - every time I receive the header "WWW-Authenticate" but in with an error message (401 unauthorized (of course ^^ - that's clear for me^^)) - but I can't read out the header to use this for further steps (md5(username:realm:password). This is not working... I want to read out the WWW-Authenticate header (with X-headername it's also not working)

```
sendCredentials()
{
console.log("Send cred");
this.http.get(this.targetUrl, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate'));
}) //Normally i want to set the nonce here and then i 
 //want to generate my md5 Value to send this in the next step with a new http get request)
}
```

I don't know how I could solve this problem - google is in this case no help for me...

I hope somebody can help me ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in my solution:

I wrote my own class to use digest Auth:

If someone is interested: (it is working for me - but not full HTTP Digest Auth Standard)
-> NC and Nonce will send on first step by my Server, username and password readed from HTML form

```
    export class AuthComponent {

  loggedIn: string = "false";
  sessionID: string = "n.s";
  username = "";
  password = "";
  targetUrl: string = "<<targetUrl>>";

  md5gen: Md5 = new Md5();
  nc = "<<your nc>>";
  nonce = "";
  opaque = "";
  qop = "";
  realm = "";
  uri = "";
  cNonce = '<<your nonce>>';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private toast: HotToastService) 
  {
    this.http.get<authModel>(this.targetUrl).subscribe(res =>
      {
          console.log(res);
          this.loggedIn = res.loggedIn;
          this.nc = res.counter;
          this.nonce = res.nonce;
          this.opaque = res.opaque;
          this.qop = res.qop;
          this.realm = res.realm;
          this.uri = res.uri;
          this.username = res.username;
      })
   }


   sendCredentials() {    
    //Create needed Hashes or auth
    this.md5gen.start();
    var A1 = this.md5gen.appendStr(this.username + ":" + this.realm + ":" + this.password).end();
    
    this.md5gen.start();
    var A2 = this.md5gen.appendStr("GET:" + this.uri).end();

    var stuff = A1 + ":" + this.nonce + ":" + this.nc + ":" + this.cNonce + ":" + this.qop + ":" + A2;
    
    this.md5gen.start();
    var resp =  this.md5gen.appendStr(stuff).end();

    /*
    console.log("Response: " + resp);
    console.log(this.password + " -> " + A1);
    console.log(resp);
    console.log("---------------");
    console.log("RQ-Method: " + "GET", 0);
    console.log("RQ-Uri: " + res.uri, 0);
    console.log("RQ-NONCE: " + res.nonce, 0 );
    console.log("RQ-NC: " + this.nc, 0 );
    console.log("RQ-CNONCE: " + cNonce, 0 );
    console.log("RQ-QOP: " + res.qop, 0 );
    */

    var header = 
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'requestModule' : 'auth-Module',
          'Authorization': 'Digest username="' + this.username + '", realm="' + this.realm + '", nonce="' + this.nonce + '", uri="' + this.uri + '", response="' + resp + '", opaque="' + this.opaque + '", qop=' + this.qop + ', nc=' + this.nc + ', cnonce="' + this.cNonce + '"',
        }
      )
    }

    this.http.get<boolean>(this.targetUrl + "/auth", header).subscribe(
      res => {
        if(res == true)
        {
          successToast(this.toast, 'Successfully loggedIn! - Welcome ' + this.username);
          console.log("Logged In!");
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
        else
        {
          if(res == null)
          {
            console.log("No Data!");

          }
          else
          {
            console.log("Wrong User/Pass!");
          }
          errorToast(this.toast, 'Wrong password or username!');
        }
      },
      err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
      () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
    )
      }

  
    }
```